# Does OpsHub handle branches when migrating from TFS to Visual Studio Online?

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am planning to migrate TFS projects to VSO in the next week or two using the Ops Hub Utility.  I wanted to ask if anyone has experience of this and can tell me if branches will still work after the migration?  Branches tend to code from one Team Project branched in to a different Team Project.  All Team Projects will be migrated together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, OpsHub support "Branch" during the migration. See the "Functionalities Supported" instruction from OpsHub for details:
http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/products/vsomigrationutility

> Support for following change type: add, edit, rename, delete, branch,
>   merge, and type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, branches **across** projects are supported by our utility. You will have to select all the projects in question to retain the branch-merge relationship in the VSO. As long as all of them are migrated, the relationship will be maintained.